# Maintain unique user name in Test methods?

Tags: apex, unit-test

I had a test class in org which has user name "test@myOrg.com'. Recently we had an issue saying that the user exist already in same or different org.

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: DUPLICATE_USERNAME, Duplicate Username.
> The username already
>   exists in this or another Salesforce organization. Usernames must be
>   unique across all Salesforce organizations. To resolve, use a
>   different username (it doesn't need to match the user's email
>   address). : [Username]

How can I keep the user name unique?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It would be more usable to have a reusable utility method.

I used to follow an example, following code from the documentation is much closer to it - [How to resolve DUPLICATE_USERNAME error returned while performing a deployment](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000182266&type=1)

```java
public static User createTestUser(Id roleId, Id profID, String fName, String lName) {
    String orgId = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();
    String dateString = String.valueof(Datetime.now())
        .replace(' ', '')
        .replace(':', '')
        .replace('-', '');
    Integer randomInt = Integer.valueOf(math.rint(math.random() * 1000000));
    String uniqueName = orgId + dateString + randomInt;
    User tuser = new User(
        firstname = fName,
        lastName = lName,
        email = uniqueName + '@test' + orgId + '.org',
        Username = uniqueName + '@test' + orgId + '.org',
        EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1',
        Alias = uniqueName.substring(18, 23),
        TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
        LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
        LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
        ProfileId = profId,
        UserRoleId = roleId
    );
    return tuser;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

This is a common issue as usernames are shared across instances, but not across environments (production/sandbox). In order to resolve this, I recommend you build your username dynamically i.e make use of prefixing with OrgId + Timestamp.

```
String orgId = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();
String dateString = String.valueof(Datetime.now()).replace(' ','').replace(':','').replace('-','');
String uniqueName = orgId + dateString;
```

Having the `unique name` as your username prefix will prevent duplications on an insert call.

**Update**

The use of each replace method may confuse you therefore I offer another solution to generate the timestamp portion of the dynamic prefix. Both will work, your preference over which String to append.

```
String dateString = String.valueof(Datetime.now().getTime());
```

Comment: FYI you can get `dateString` more simply using the `format` method, e.g. `Datetime.now().format('yyyyMMddHHmmss')`.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use "test.com" or "contoso.com" or some generic domain like that. Almost everyone at some point has used those addresses because they figure that they shouldn't be cluttering up their own domain with useless usernames. That's really a bad practice, because it does cause complications. Use your *own* domain name, just with some crazy variation that wouldn't normally be used. For example, if I worked for Microsoft, I'd probably use a username like "unit.test.user@microsoft.com.unit.test." At my current organization, I use our domain name for test users, because I can be fairly certain nobody else is using it. In addition, I also generate the username randomly so parallel tests don't interfere with each other. I always stick to using our own domain name, though, so I don't collide with other orgs.